# Can not find mnr_getWork method

Tags: bitcoin, mining, rsk

I am going to run my own private merged mining pool compatible with RSK.
I have installed ckpool on my server. ckpool is merged mining pool software written by C.
I installed RSK and BTC node on my server. FOR RSK I used ubuntu package. Ubuntu version is 22.04. When I run this pool, this error is caused  """"""""""" rsk node is not activate """"""".
I have reviewed code and found that error is caused in this part.

""""""""""""""
static const char *rsk_getwork_req = "{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "mnr_getWork", "params": [], "id": %d}\n";

"""""""""""""
According to the result of my research, mnr_work is not supported anymore over RSK version 3.0.
In this version we need to use getblocktemplate method instead of mnr_getwork.
I tried to replace mnr_getWork with getblocktemplate but still the error is caused.
How can I fix this error.

If anyone has got experience in installation of ckpool, please help me.

I have used curl command to check that rsk node is response properly for my request.
The command is as below.

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getblocktemplate","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:4444/

the result is as below.
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"method not found"}}

What is error?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that probably the `mnr_` family of methods is not enabled by default.
You can do that by adding it to the `node.conf` file:

```
rpc.modules = [
    {
        name: "eth",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "net",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "rpc",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "web3",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "evm",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "sco",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "txpool",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "personal",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "debug",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "rsk",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "mnr",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
]
```

Comment: I have tried this but it does not work properly. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you send me your contact information. i want to keep in touch with you.

Comment: would need more detail in order to understand what isn't working. "getblocktemplate" is not a JSON-RPC method, that is why you get the "method not found" message. 

You can check that your Rootstock node is running and reachable with:


```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4444/ \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1}'
```

Comment: also, there is a discord server [here](https://discord.com/invite/rootstock-842021106956238848) where you can find support for rootstock

Comment: did you follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/rsksmart/ckpool/blob/master/README_Rootstock.txt) ?